# SMW queries: Move main column to other position

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

As far as I understand a tabular result of a SMW query always contains the page title. This is presented in the leftmost column. Can this title column be moved to some other position as well? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to list the page title (`?`) explicitly in the printouts.

The example below assumes that you have the special property *[Creation date](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Property:Creation_date)* activated.

```
<!-- Pages created today -->
{{#ask:
[[Creation date::>={{#time:d.m.Y}}]]
|?Creation date
|?=An optional title for this column
|format = table
}}
```

Comment: see https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries#Standard_parameters_for_inline_queries mainlabel parameter